# How to 'load' data into a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Trying to wrap my head around components and I'm having a hard time translating the official vuejs.org guide examples (which largely use `new Vue({...})`) to the module structure offered with a fresh Vue app generated with the CLI.

If I have something like

```js
const products = {
  'bat': '9.99',
  'glove': '7.50',
  'cleets': '12.50'
}
```

How do I 'load' that into a component?

Products.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <li v-for="product in products">
      {{ product }}
    </li>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Products',
    data: function () {
      products: ??   // <-- My understanding is the products data would be added here somehow?
    }
  }
</script>
```

And then, in the 'Home.vue' component, something like

```html
<template>
   <div>
      <Products />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Products from "@/components/Products.vue";

  export default {
    name: "Home",
    components: {
      Products,
    },
  };
</script>
```

Any pointers? Thanks for any help! And sorry if it's something that should be obvious, it's frustrating to not be able to figure out a rather basic concept to Vue.js :(

---

Per @A.khalifa's response I modified `Products.vue` to the following

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Products',
  data: function() {
    products: [{
      'bat': '9.99',
      'glove': '7.50',
      'cleets': '12.50'
    }]
  }
}
</script>
```

That now returns the following errors

```
10:5  error  Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives  vue/require-v-for-key
23:5  error  'products:' is defined but never used                           no-unused-labels
```

I'm not sure what to do about the `v-bind:key` directive... As for `products` am I not referencing it properly within the directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to return an object from your `data`

```js
data: function () {
    return {
        products: {
          'bat': '9.99',
          'glove': '7.50',
          'cleets': '12.50'
        }
    }
}
```

or

```js
data() {
    return {
        products: {
          'bat': '9.99',
          'glove': '7.50',
          'cleets': '12.50'
        }
    }
}
```

and on your template

```js
<li v-for="(price, name) in products" :key="name">
    {{ name }} = {{ price }}
</li>
```

Read more about components basic here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Base-Example

And using `v-for` with object here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object

Comment: Ahh yes! You're absolutely right, I forgot to `return` things. Thank you so much @Owl!

And for the output too, works like a charm :)